# Get value of databound cell in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been trying this out for a while now and can't seem to figure it out. I can extract the controls in the gridview fine, but I need to get the values of the databound cells in the GridView, and cant seem to find out how. Here is my code:

Webpage:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="ReceiverPanel" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ODSPopulatePOItemList">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PurchaseOrderID" HeaderText="PurchaseOrderID" SortExpression="PurchaseOrderID" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StockItemID" HeaderText="StockItemID" SortExpression="StockItemID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityOnOrder" HeaderText="QuantityOnOrder" SortExpression="QuantityOnOrder" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityOutstanding" HeaderText="Outstanding" SortExpression="QuantityOutstanding" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Receive">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Received" Text='<%# Eval("Received") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Return">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Returned" Text='<%# Eval("ReturnedQuantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Reason" Text='<%# Eval("Reason") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void ReceiveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Gather data from gridview
    foreach (GridViewRow row in ReceiverPanel.Rows)
    {
        // Find controls in the Gridview
        //var purchaseOrderIdCtrl = row.FindControl("PurchaseOrderID") as HiddenField;
        //var stockItemCtrl = row.FindControl("")
        var receivedCtrl = row.FindControl("Received") as TextBox;
        var returnedCtrl = row.FindControl("Returned") as TextBox;
        var reasonCtrl = row.FindControl("Reason") as TextBox;
        //SELECT DATABOUND CONTROL var stockItemNo = row.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text ;

        //int stockItemNum = int.Parse(stockItemNo);
        int received = int.Parse(receivedCtrl.Text);
        int returned = int.Parse(returnedCtrl.Text);
        string reason = reasonCtrl.Text;

        Update_StockItem(stockItemNum, received);
    }
```

Is there a simple way to grab the values from the GridView? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

You Need Specify Index of Bound Field Like `PurchaseOrderID` is first `BoundField` so its index is `0`

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in ReceiverPanel.Rows)
    {
         string PurchaseOrderID =row.Cells[0].Text


    }
```

Comment: That gives me an error message under "Row" stating there is no definition of it.

Comment: I did this for named columns (It's VB.net but you can get the point):
    Dim ID As Integer = Me.DataGridView.DataSource.Rows(Me.DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index)(Me.dgvIDTextBox.DisplayIndex)